# Why do I get Ubuntu Classic instead of Unity the first time I log in after rebooting?

Tags: unity, login, reboot

Recently, my Ubuntu Natty system has started to log me into Ubuntu Classic (i.e. GNOME desktop) instead of Unity the first time I log in after a reboot. I have made sure to select "Unity" from the session menu before logging in. Every subsequent login works fine until the next reboot.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there has been some change in the video configuration or the graphics card driver has been updated, unity doesn't support that change/update and, consequently, it falls to classic desktop.

Anyway, I'd take a look at /var/log to verify if some problem regarding unity has been logged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default in your login screen settings? I.E. ***System -> Administration -> Login Screen*** I don't see why that would have a solid effect because it's almost the same thing as the actual login screen settings you do when logging in but you never know.

Comment: Yes, the default session is set to "Ubuntu".